# How to remove the selected text from text file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My text is shown in above link, there I would like to keep text in between keyword "--#pipeline" and "--#pipeline" rest keyword lines like "--#nonpipelined" to delete and write it in another new file.
 In short in new file should contain all text exept text mentioned in between "--#nonpipelined".

Here I tried:

```
         file=open("vhdl.txt","w+")
         file1=open("new.txt","w")
         q1="--#pipeline"
```

for line in file:
  if line =="--#":
     if line == q1:
        break
         if line =="--#."
            file1.write(line)

Comment: what have you tried so far? We won't do everything for you

Comment: I don't see any effort of solving it, what have you tried? Where you got stuck? Did you encounter any error?

Comment: I tried many ways but it didn't work..i know its simple but some how am struck..my mind not working right now

Comment: finally, I found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like a boolean flag to pick up when you want to ignore a line

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    ignore = False
    for line in f:
        pipelined = f.startswith("--#pipeline")
        ignore = (pipelined and not ignore) 
        if not ignore:
            print(line)
```

Use CLI output redirection to get a new file

```
python script.py > output.txt
```

Comment: for every line i don't have key word to delete text, but in my text below to keyword "--#pipeline" some text after some lines again same keyword "--#pipeline" will repeat and i want to delete lines between keyword "--#pipeline". rest lines in code it should print as it is

Comment: This is looping over each line, ignoring some between a phrase (i didn't actually test it)... You need to know your keyword to search for deletion, otherwise you could just give any character, and according to your logic, everything between that character and the next occurrence of it will be removed

Comment: thank you for your response, its working only thing is this is ignoring the particular line not text in between key words

Comment: its instruction line = next(file name ) we need to use

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
string = """   --shb hdjhsjkcjdbcjbdhcbhcc jsbjcbdkjbdskjcbkjsdjc jdcnjksdncjk kjbckjbdskj

   --#pipelined 
jck jhcdjdh jdhcdbcbdh hcbdhjbdc jbdcwjk jdbjkcbwjk kwjcbkjwdbcj kwjbdkjbchjkew
   --#pipelined 
   --#non pipleined scbkjs cjdjke jcedj
ujcdhuidh
jcdjnj
jkdbcjknsd
   --#non pipelined hcsbhsd cjdjd"""

clean = re.sub(r'--#pipelined\s*(.*?)\s*--#pipelined', '', string)
```

now you can write the clean object to any file you want.

Comment: sorry i idn't get, can you please explain wat u did

Comment: r'--#pipelined\s*(.*?)\s*--#pipelined'  this part not working